# Is there a way where I can minimize execution time of a google apps script through triggers?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

So, let's think of it like this:
I have 20 units of data where the processing of each unit takes 1 minute to be processed (total 20 minutes of processing), and the maximum execution time for an apps script function is (360 seconds), the thing is I dont want to divide them to like 4 parallel executions manually so I thought of this:

1. make a driver function to get the 20 units at once 2) check for
   current triggers.
2. if < 20 triggers are there, divide the units by the available     triggers to create some sort of concurrency (then the whole execution will finish in 1 minute if n of triggers atm is 0.
3. if >=20 (max limit) sleep for a minute then check for available triggers again
4. run a function to delete each trigger after it finishes execution.

so is this achievable or is there a better way to workaround the max execution time and the concurrency problems in apps script?

Comment: Your best bet is optimizing your existing functions. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  Best practices. What you're saying looks possible, but there's a total  trigger runtime of 90 minutes/day.

Comment: I doubt that the server is going to allocate threads on the basis of triggers.

Comment: did not know about the 90 minutes/day quota..., the thing is the functions are optimized as much as possible, but due to some external calls to firebase for example and whatsoever, they take alot of time, is there anything besides apps scripts that can make the same things the apps scripts is doing?

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about your situation? About your 20 units, when each unit is processed, does the result of each unit independents for each result of units? Or, does the result of each unit depend on each result of each unit? If it's the former, I thought that the asynchronous process can be used. If it's the latter, I thought that it is required to run the script with the synchronous process.

Comment: no each unit is independent from the other units, it's just I want to run them in parallel instead of normally them running one after another

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From `no each unit is independent from the other units`, in this case, when each unit is run with the asynchronous process, how do you want to do about the response value of each unit?

Comment: let's say each unit is converted to JSON which is used to update a firestore database, Instead of the code doing the 20 updates 1 after the other, I want it to start doing the 20 concurrently

Comment: Even external calls can be optimized. There's very little reason, why your function shouldn't finish within 6 minutes. I think Tanaike is also going to point out how external calls can be optimized in his answer. Editing in a [mcve] would help others a lot in optimizing scripts.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Sorry. Now I noticed your replying. In your situation, each unit only converts data, and you want to retrieve the converted data. In this case, each unit doesn't put the converted data to Firestore. Is my understanding correct? By the way, when you add `@` to the username like `@username`, the user can notice your reply.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you, I didn't know that..., yes each unit do some data processing to convert data in spreadsheet to JSON and then it puts it in a firestore database and each unit is independent from the other so I don't care which data gets sent to firestore first.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You have 20 units.
- At each unit, you want to convert the data.

  - You have already created the script for converting the data.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.
- You want to reduce the cost of this process.

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no methods for directly running the Google Apps Script with the asynchronous process. So, in order to achieve your goal, it is required to think of a workaround. In this answer, I would like to propose a workaround. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. Web Apps is deployed.

   - Your current script for converting the data is used with Web Apps.
2. In order to achieve the asynchronous process, a Google Apps Script library is used. [Ref](https://github.com/tanaikech/RunAll)

   - This library achieves the asynchronous process using the fetchAll method of Class UrlFetchApp. [Ref](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c0f383034045ab63c19604139ecb0728)

By this, the script can be run with the asynchronous process.

### Usage:

#### 1. Install a library.

Please install the library to your current Google Apps Script project. You can see the method for installing it at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/RunAll#how-to-install-1).

#### 2. Prepare sample script.

```js
// This is your current script.
function myFunction(e) {

  // do something.
  //return result; // Please return the values you want to return.

  return e; // This is a sample return value for testing this script.
}

function doPost(e) {
  return RunAll.RunFunctionsByDoPost(this, e);
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  var url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev"; // Here, please set the URL of Web Apps.
  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var resource = [
    {
      functionName: "myFunction",
      arguments: "sample parameter 1", // Please set the value you want to give.
      webAppsURL: url,
      accessToken: token,
    },
    {
      functionName: "myFunction",
      arguments: "sample parameter 2", // Please set the value you want to give.
      webAppsURL: url,
      accessToken: token,
    },
    {
      functionName: "myFunction",
      arguments: "sample parameter 3", // Please set the value you want to give.
      webAppsURL: url,
      accessToken: token,
    },
  ];
  var res = RunAll.DoWebApps(resource);
  res.forEach(function (r) {
    Logger.log(r.getContentText());
  });
}
```

- This is a sample script. Of cource, you can create the value of `resouece` using a loop.

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"User accessing the web app"** or **"Me"** for "Execute the app as:".
3. Select **"Only myself"** for "Who has access to the app:".

   - By this setting, Web Apps can be accessed by only you who are the owner. If "Anyone, even anonymous" is set, all people who know the URL of Web Apps can be accessed. So please be careful.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Copy the URL of "latest code" of "Test web app for your latest code.".

   - It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/dev`.
7. Click "OK".

- By this, even when the script in the project deployed Web Apps was modified, the latest script can be automatically used.
- In this setting, the deployed Web Apps in the project is accessed from the script in the same project.

#### 4. Testing:

When above script is run, when your setting is correct, the following result is obtained.

```
{"FunctionName":"myFunction","Arguments":"sample parameter 1","Result":"sample parameter 1"}

{"FunctionName":"myFunction","Arguments":"sample parameter 2","Result":"sample parameter 2"}

{"FunctionName":"myFunction","Arguments":"sample parameter 3","Result":"sample parameter 3"}
```

### Note:

- When I tested this script, the maximum number of workers is 29. So I thought that this workaround might be able to use to your situation. But I'm not sure about your actual script. So when this number cannot be used, please modify it.

#### References:

- [Benchmark: fetchAll method in UrlFetch service for Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c0f383034045ab63c19604139ecb0728)
- [RunAll](https://github.com/tanaikech/RunAll)

  - This is a library for running the concurrent processing using only native Google Apps Script (GAS).

Comment: @Youssef Ahmed By the way, although I'm not sure your actual script for converting the data, if your script has the modification points for reducing the process cost, I thought that it might become the direct solution. How about this?

Comment: I will try this workaround, thank you